# How can I make Django create migration files for tables that aren't Django managed?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

## Background

I've got a Django app that I want to test. The Django app relies on database tables that were created by a different, non-Django app, but in the same database.  Every time I try to run a test I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "mytable" does not exist
```

I'm thinking that this error is caused by the fact that the table was created manually and there are no migrations.

## Question

Is there a way I can tell Django to build migration files based off of a database table that already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called `inspectdb` in Django for this exact scenario.

This should do the trick:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

For reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/